# Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working in VueJS and I need to delete a topic and then scroll to the next item after the deletion was made.

Here is the code:

```
deleteTopic: function (index) {
                        var lcID="";
                        if(index===0) {
                            lcID = '#cAccordion-'+(index+1);
                        }
                        else {
                            lcID = '#cAccordion-'+index;
                        }
                        this.agenda.topics.splice(index, 1);
                        document.querySelector(lcID).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'});
                        this.confirmDeleteTopicIndex = -1;                  
                    }
```

It's working perfectly EXCEPT if I delete the first item, that's when I get the error: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null.

In the code I'm checking for a zero index. It works...it will scroll but I'd like to get rid of the error.

Comment: Just debug the code. Most probably there is no element in the DOM with one of the ids set by `lcID`

Comment: You could also make use of references into your template ! https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref This way you would be able to check the existence of your dom element in an easier way

Comment: I am trying to debug the code. It should work. as there will always be a '#cAccordion-'+(index+1); I'll keep trying :-) I will also look up $refs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I set a timer as I said... here is the code.

```
setTimeout(function() {document.querySelector(lcID).scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'});}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I there. I placed a timer on it and it worked perfectly. The DOM had to update.